How to interpret: $ f(x)=g(x)(1+r(x))$ where $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}r(x)=0$?
Consider two functions $f$ and $g$ and assume that
$$
(1) \quad f(x)=g(x)(1+r(x))\quad \text{where $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}r(x)=0$}
$$
I  would like to understand how to interpret (1). Reading the useful comments below, (1) describes functions that are relatively close. In particular, (1) says that
$$
(2) \quad \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1
$$
What I am confused about is the relation of (1) (or, equivalently (2)) with the notion of absolute closeness. In particular, assume that, in addition to (1), it holds that:
$$
(3) \quad \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} g(x)=0. 
$$
Question: (3) is not sufficient for (2); (2) is not sufficient for (3) (I think). Therefore, can I read (2) and (3) together as saying somehow that not only both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ go to zero, but they do it in a "coordinated way"? Can you help me formalise this better, perhaps using the notion of rate of convergence?

That is the definition of "$f$ is asymptotic to $g$", often written as $f\sim g$. It doesn't always mean that $f$ and $g$ get absolutely closer (for example, if $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x+1$, $f$ and $g$ are always one unit appart), but rather relatively closer ($f/g \to 1$). If one the limits of (2) exist, then the other also exist, and the equality holds!

Thanks. When you say "if one of the limits of (2) exists": do you mean "exists and is finite"?

It could also be an infinite limit (as long as it exists)!

Suppose $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x+1$ as in your example. Then, $\lim_{x\rightarrow} f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow} g(x)=\infty$. Therefore, (2) holds. Does this mean that these two functions are BOTH absolutely and relatively closer? Can you give me an example of two functions which are relatively but not absolutely closer?

@Star Here is an example of two functions which are relatively but not absolutely closer: $f_1(x)=x^2 + x$ and $f_2(x) = x^2.$ Then $f_1(x)-f_2(x)\to\infty, $ so the functions are not absolutely close, but $f_1(x)/f_2(x) \to 1,$ so they are relatively close. That is just one example, and I challenge you to come up with some more of your own.

The definition of absolutely and relatively closer are not usual, but there I mean $|f(x)-g(x)|=1\not\to 0$ so $f$ and $g$ don't get absolutely close. However, $|f(x)-g(x)|/f(x)\to 0$ so $f$ and $g$ get relatively close.

@AdamRubinson I'm not sure about your example.

@Kolakoski54 we definitely have $x^2+x \sim x^2$

@julio_es_sui_glace of course, now that it has been edited.

The study of Stirling equivalent (You can extend it to a real function using the gamma function), or the harmonic series gives you interesting examples of asymptotically equivalent functions/sequences. Basically it means $f = g + o(g)$. This relation is an equivalence relation and it is not really hard to show.

This property is called "asymptotical equivalence" and is in fact an equivalence relation, so let us show it.
Definition and properties
Let $f,g$ to real functions, we say that $f \sim g$ if there exists a real function $\epsilon$ such that $f = g(1+\epsilon)$ and $\epsilon(x) \to 0$ when $x \to \infty$.

Of course with $\epsilon = 0$ we have $f \sim f$
For $f\sim g$ and $g \sim h$ with given $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$, we have
$$f = g(1+\epsilon_1) = h(1+\epsilon_2)(1+\epsilon_1) = h(1 + \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 + \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2)$$
so by setting $\epsilon_3 = \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2 + \epsilon_1 \epsilon_2$ we get $f = h (1 +\epsilon_3)$ so $f \sim g$.
If $f \sim g$ with $\epsilon$, we know that for $x > X$ we have $|\epsilon(x)|<1 $, so for such $x$
$$g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{1 + \epsilon(x)} = f(x) (1 - \epsilon(x) + \epsilon(x)^2 \delta(x))$$
where $\delta$ is bounded.
We now set $\epsilon'(x) = - \epsilon(x) + \epsilon(x)^2 \delta(x)$ for $x>X$ and for $x \le X$ when $f(x) \neq 0$ we set $\epsilon'(x) = \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}-1$ and when $f(x) = 0$ we set $\epsilon'(x) = -1$.
Now $\forall x$ we have $g(x) = f(x) (1+\epsilon'(x))$ thus $g \sim f$.

We just proved that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. It has a few properties: when $f\sim f'$ and $g \sim g'$

$fg \sim f'g'$
If $f$ and $f'$ never vanish, $\frac{1}{f} \sim \frac{1}{f'}$.
If $\lim_\infty f = \infty$ then $g \circ f \sim g' \circ f'$

Furthermore, if $g$ never vanishes, $f \sim g \iff \frac{f}{g} (x) \to 1$ when $x \to \infty$ just compute:
$$\frac{f}{g} = 1 + \epsilon \to 1$$
and if $\frac{f}{g} \to 1$ then $\epsilon = \frac{f}{g}-1 \to 0$ and $f = g(1+\epsilon)$.
Now if $f\sim g$ and  $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = l$ with $l$ finite, then necessarily $\lim_{x \to \infty } g = l$. One can just see that $f = g + \delta$ with $\delta \to 0$ and $f = (l + \delta) (1 + \epsilon) = l + \delta + l\epsilon + \delta \epsilon \to l$.
Of cours it is the same for infinite $l$. the idea is that $g$ behaves like $f$ when approaching infinity.

Of course you can replace $x$ by $n$ if you want to work with sequences. You can also replace $\infty$ by any point of $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ the definitions still work.

There is one equivalent formulation using the $o$ notation:
$$f \sim g \iff f = g + o(g)$$
Hazards to avoid

We don't have $f \sim f'$, $g \sim g' \implies f+g \sim f' + g'$, take for example $f(x) = -g(x) = -g'(x) = x^2$ and $f'(x) = x^2 + x$ then $f + g = 0$ and $f'(x) + g'(x) = x$.
It is not compatible with $\log$ or $\exp$, e.g. take $f(x) = x^2$ $g(x) = x^2 + x$,
$$\frac{e^{g(x)}}{e^{f(x)}} = e^x \to \infty$$
so it does not converges to $1$.
For the $\log$ just take $f(x) = 1$ and $g(x) = 1 + \frac{1}{x}$, we get
$$\frac{\log(f(x))}{\log(g(x))} = 0$$
which never tends to $1$.

Examples
Of course you have easy examples like $x \sim x + 1/x$, but sometimes the difference does not tend to zero (you can see that it was already said in the comments). There are already well known equivalents:

If $p$ and $q$ are polynomials of dominant monic which are respectfully $aX^m$ and $bX^n$, then $\frac{p}{q} (x)\sim \frac{a}{b} x^{m-n}$.
The Stirling equivalent $n! \sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{n^n}{e^n}$, and here the difference is still very big: $n!- \sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{n^n}{e^n} \sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{n}}\frac{n^n}{12e^n}$.
The harmonic series give you $\sum_{0<k\leq n} \frac{1}{k} \sim \ln(n)$ and here the difference is equivalent to a constant called the Euler-Mascheroni constant: $\sum_{0<k\leq n} \frac{1}{k} - \ln(n) \sim \gamma$

Some comments
As I mentioned if $f \sim g$ they have the same asymptotic behavior, now if you want to talk about convergence rate, $\sim$ is compatible with the $O,o, \Omega$ and $\theta$ notations. In particular
$$f \sim g \implies f = \theta(g).$$
But the converse is not true, just take $g=(2+\sin)f$.
